# Why we can use U-Substitution in above one and not in 2nd one.

Tags: calculus

So here is the one that author used u substitution though i dont know what happened to cos

[image]

here is the one that author said can't be done with substitution

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. It's a substitution: So $u=\sin(x) \Rightarrow du = \cos(x) dx$.

We replace $\sin(x)$ with $u$ and $du$ replaces $\cos(x) dx$.

B. If we try to do $u$-substitution on the second once no matter how you try to rewrite $\sin(x)$ the integrand will not work out with elementary techniques.

For example: $\sin^5(x) = \sin^3(x)\sin^2(x) = \sin^3(x)(1-\cos^2(x))$. In any example we will see that the method of u-substituion will only get rid of one of the powers of the trig functions $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$ depending on how you try to rewite the integrand.

Answer (score 1):

After some manipulation, the second integral can be done by substitution. Note that $\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2 x$, and therefore
$$\int \sin ^5 x\,dx=\int(1-\cos^2 x)^2\sin x\,dx.$$
Let $u=\cos x$. Then $du=-\sin x \,dx$, and therefore
$$\int (1-\cos^2 x)^2\sin x\,dx=\int-(1-u^2)^2\,du.$$
To finish, expand $-(1-u^2)^2$, and integrate term by term. We get
$$-u+\frac{2u^3}{3}-\frac{u^5}{5}+C.$$